# Systemd: how to make a systemd service start after network fully connected?

Tags: systemd, startup

**Background**

I am writing a simple script to be running in Raspbain on Raspberry Pi 2, simple turn a LED on to indicate I am ready to connect with SSH from my desktop computer.

The script is not important here, only to mention that as I use frequence control so the script is running an infinite loop, to turn the LED on and off frequently. So this is an example of simple service. However, at least [the accepted answer of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/544399/how-do-you-make-a-systemd-service-as-the-last-service-on-boot) advise me to set the type to idle. So my service file looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn on LED after SSH is ready

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshready.py

[Install]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

**Effect**

The service runs as expected. However, I noticed when I start putty in my desktop computer right after the LED turns on the login prompt not appear immidiately. So I checked with

```
$ systemd-analyze plot > output.svg
```

The result shows

[image]

**Question**

It looks like my services starts not after `network-online.target`, what is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When there is a question about a systemd directive, you can use `man systemd.directives` to find where it's documented. In this case it shows that `After=` is documented in `man systemd.unit`.

In that file, it shows that `After=` directive is listed in the "[UNIT] SECTION OPTIONS", indicating that it belongs in the `[Unit]` section of the file.

The same documentation also documents the [INSTALL] section options, and `After=` is not listed there.

In short, your `After=` directive was in the wrong location the unit file so it had no effect until you moved it to the correct location.

Comment: To be clear, in this case "[Unit]" is "[Service]", since it's a service file.

Answer (score 15):

Have it fixed by modifying the service as

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn on LED after SSH is ready
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshready.py

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

Still didn't fully understand what I was doing, but it works now. Can anyone please explain?

**Update**

This answer was created by myself before the accepted answer comes.

Comment: That the `After=`directive must be in the `[Unit]` section. It's just that.